# Join two tables SQL

Tags: sql

I am a newbie in SQL.

I have 2 tables  :

1. "category" (two columns "id" and "category_name")
2. "brand" (two columns "id" and "brand_name")

And I want to display a table that shows the brand depending to the category for exemple :

```
ID__________Category ______________Brand    
1___________category-a _____________brand-x    
2___________category-b _____________brand-y    
3___________category-c______________brand-z    
4___________category-d______________brand-x    
5___________category-e______________brand-x    
6___________category-e______________brand-y
```

Each brand can be in 1 or n category, and each category can got 1 or n brands.

Do I have to create another table to merge the 2 tables ? I am a bit confused because I read some sql tutorials but the examples given are not for 2 associatives tables.
Thanks :)

Comment: It sounds like the relationship between categories and brands is *many-to-many.*  You model this in the database by using a *[bridge table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).*

Answer (score 1):

You would generally create an intermediate table which maps the relationship (many to many in this case).

```
brand_category
    category_id    brand_id
```

You can then do things like:

```
-- Get all brands for a category
SELECT * FROM brand 
INNER JOIN brand_category ON (brand.id = brand_category.brand_id AND brand_category.category_id = 12)

-- List all brands along with categories
SELECT brand.name,category.name FROM brand 
LEFT JOIN brand_category ON (brand.id = brand_category.brand_id)
LEFT JOIN category ON (brand_category.category_id = category.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a connecting table, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE category_brand (
 category_id NUMERIC,
 brand_id NUMERIC,
);

ALTER TABLE category_brand
ADD CONSTRAINT category_brand_pk PRIMARY KEY (category_id, brand_id);
```

Now, you can query with a join:

```
SELECT category, brand
FROM   category c
JOIN   category_brand cb ON c.category_id = cb.category_id
JOIN   brand b ON cb.brand_id = b.brand_id
```

Comment: just remove " , " at the end of the line : brand_id NUMERIC

Comment: thanks for the answer :) But How can I select the column brand from the table category ? In this column I have only the column "category"

Answer (score 0):

The connection between brands and categories is many-to-many. That means, it has to be another BrandCategory table, containing primary keys from both brands and categories.